# Who is $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}^m,\mathbb{Z}^n)$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

The problem is:

> Who is $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}^m,\mathbb{Z}^n)$ isomorphic to? (where $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}^m,\mathbb{Z}^n)=\{f:\mathbb{Z}^m\to\mathbb{Z}^n\mid f  \text{ homomorphism  of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules}\}$)

Comment: Hint: where can the generator go?

Comment: What if $m=1$? In fact, do both equal to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find useful the follow isomorphisms of abelian groups (and these are isomorphism of $R$-modules when $R$ is commutative):
$$\text{Hom}_R(L\oplus M,N)\cong \text{Hom}_R(L,N)\oplus \text{Hom}_R(M,N),$$
$$\text{Hom}_R(L,M\oplus N)\cong \text{Hom}_R(L,M)\oplus \text{Hom}_R(L,N).$$
So, $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}^m,\mathbb{Z}^n)\cong\text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z})^{mn}.$ Do you know what $\text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to?

Comment: Im not convinced about $\text{Hom}_R(L\oplus M,N)\cong \text{Hom}_R(L,N)\oplus \text{Hom}_R(M,N)$, and $\text{Hom}_R(L,M\oplus N)\cong \text{Hom}_R(L,M)\oplus \text{Hom}_R(L,N).$

Comment: $\text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Given a homomorphism $f:L\oplus M\to N$, check that $(\left. f\right|_L,\left.f\right|_M)$ gives you a pair of well-defined homomorphisms and that this assignment is an abelian group homomorphism. Find the two-sided inverse to this map to show that it is an isomorphism, and do similarly for the second isomorphism by projecting the image of $f$ onto $M$ and $N$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $R$ be  any (commutative) ring. For any free $R$-module $F$ with basis $(x_i)_{i\in I}$, and any $R$-module $M$,
$$\operatorname{Hom}_R(F,M)\simeq M^I. $$

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped what I meant: $M^I$ , where $I$ is the cardinal (possibly transfinite of a basis for $F$. I've corrected my answer. Of course $M^I$ is simply the set of maps from  $I$ into $M$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Every $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map $$f:\mathbb{Z}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^n$$
can be expressed as a matrix, with entries $a_{i,j}\in\mathbb{Z}$. How many choices do you have for $a_{i,j}$?